# Disable/Remove/Hide "Pages" menu or "Page Library" or "View all pages"

Tags: ribbon, pages, menu

I am using SharePoint Online. Does anyone know of ways to disable/remove/hide the "View all Pages" from the ribbon menu. I am open to solutions to remove "Page Library" section of the ribbon or even the "Page" menu if those solutions are avalable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide `Page` tab using CSS:

```
.ms-cui-tts > li:last-child {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Most Welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Script editor webpart` to the page by inserting code to hide the whole Page ribbon:

```
#Ribbon\.WikiPageTab {
  display: none !important;
}
```